# Jsoup Google News Link Scraping unable to get correct element

Tags: java, jsoup

I am having some problems with scraping google news for its links.
I followed another question which provided the code to scrape for the title and it works, however when I try to modify it to scrape for links instead it returns an empty string.

Here is the relevant code,

```
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?num=10&safe=off&tbm=nws&q=anime&oq=anime").userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(0).get();
Elements newslinks = doc.select("li[class=g]");
for (Element link : newslinks) {

    Elements linked = link.select("a[class=l]");
    String links = linked.attr("data-href");

    System.out.println("TEST" + links);

    Elements titles = link.select("h3[class=r]");
    String title = titles.text();

...
```

Got this from google.

```
<a class="l _HId" href="...not what i want here" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNGlSQSnNn69gs3dFI6wQf9ePiar4g','SZyPQ8IYl_kGgASohj4w5g','0ahUKEwiSpfzgov_JAhVHOxoKHTOpB4gQqQIIICgAMAA','','',event)" data-href="http://www.theverge.com/2015/12/22/10649396/google-login-without-password-mobile-security"><em>Google</em> is <em>testing</em> a way for users to log in without a password</a>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found that the code needs some changes. This works:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?num=10&safe=off&tbm=nws&q=anime&oq=anime").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements links = doc.select("li.g h3 a");
for (Element e: links) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + e.text());
    System.out.println("Link: " + e.attr("href"));
}
```

For this kind of thing, the developer tools in your browser are quite handy to find how the page is structured and how the data can be extracted, and there is also the [documentation for CSS selectors in Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked! Did not exactly get the URL but at least it contained the URL. Still not sure why the above code is not working though, since data-href is the attribute with the URL.

Comment: @hqjb, for me the code I posted worked perfectly, printing the title and the URL. Maybe the problem is that Google results page is structured differently in different countries.. For me there was no data-href attribute at all. Feel free to experiment with the code though.